# pubnub same app with two different keys can access the same channel with all data

Tags: pubnub

I want to use pubnub access manager for keys used on web and other set of keys without access manager on mobile devices. Can they both have access to same channels data.

Answer (score 2):

## PubNub Access Manager

No. A key set (set of pub/sub/secret keys) is a namespace for channels. So channel `abc` of key set #1 is not the same channel as `abc` from key set #2.

But with [PubNub Access Manager](https://www.pubnub.com/docs/tutorials/pubnub-access-manager), you would grant one set of permissions for channel `abc` to auth-key `user1-auth` and another set of permissions to auth-key `user2-auth`. So you do not need two sets of keys.

Comment: Thanks for clarify. :)